# Firebase, finding the key of parent based on child's value

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

essentially what I am trying to do is to create a button on a created text node in js. Then find the value of spmet and remove the question (spmet) from the database.

However I can't figure out how to properly reference it, and find the specific value that I want deleted. (so other picture, remove that question from database when I press the "x")

[this is the the way to remove questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VwWO.png)

[This is the firebase layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OhJT.png)

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var btnText = document.createTextNode("x"); //create button

btn.appendChild(btnText);
tekst.appendChild(btn);
btn.id = "questionBtn";

//bytter enter som gir linjeskift til <br>
tekst.innerHTML = tekst.innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');

chat.appendChild(bubble);

setTimeout(function(){
    chat.classList.add('visible')
}, 1);

chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight;
console.log(bubble);
// Function to remove the question on the button generated
tekst.onclick = function removeQ(){

    window.alert("Knapp funker");

    var ref = database.ref();
    ref.child('spm')
        .orderByChild('spmet')
        .equalTo(spmet)
        .once('value', function(snap) { 
        //remove the specific spmet parent
        window.alert(snap.val());

    });
    document.getElementById("cont1").removeChild(bubble); // removes text from page
    var spmRef = ??
    spmRef.remove(); //can't reference properly
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you generate the HTML element for each question, keep the ID of that question as an attribute on that HTML element:

```
ref.child("spm").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = snapshot.key;
  div.innerText = snapshot.child("spmet").val();
  div.onclick = onSpmClick;
  questionContainer.appendChild(div);
});
```

Now when the user clicks on one of the questions, you can get the key from that div and remove it:

```
function onSpmClick(e) {
  var key = e.target.id;
  ref.child("spm").child(key).remove();
}
```